# Reduce request latency on an FTDI UBS-to-RS-232 adapter

Tags: usb, wine, serial-port

I'm using an ElmScan5 scantool which uses an FTDI USB-2-[RS-232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) serial-to-USB chip under [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) 1.6.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).

The latency is very high and [I found a recommendation on how to reduce it on Windows](http://forscan.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1763), but I'm not sure how to do something similar on Linux.

In Windows under COM ports there is an option to reduce the latency timer:

> Call Device Manager, find your USB port. (1) Call Properties; (2) Call advanced (3) Change Latency Timer from 16 to 2 or 1 ms.

In order to [get the software working under Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32798) I had to add the following to the Wine registry file:

```
[Hardware\\Devicemap\\Serialcomm] 1015709345
"Serial0"="COM1"
```

So I don't know if this is a Linux or a Wine issue.

Answer (score 9):

OK, [so here's the answer](https://projectgus.com/2011/10/notes-on-ftdi-latency-with-arduino/) ( haven't tested it yet but looks good):

```
# cat /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer
16
# echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer
# cat /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer
1
```

The only annoying thing is that it looks like I may have to manually set it every time a unplug then plug back in the device, or at least on every reboot.

Comment: reading kernel sources (4.11) it appears that you can set the same thing from the shell (setserial /dev/ttyUSB0 low_latency), which uses the `TIOCSSERIAL` ioctl.

Comment: "echo 1 >...tty..." is always denied even for sudo while "setserial /dev/ttyUSB0 low_latency" works good

Comment: This may be a little old but can help some in the future. You cannot just append `sudo` to the beginning of the command. You have to type `sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer'`. The former just runs `echo` as su, while the redirection is made by the shell, which runs as your user.

Comment: Worked perfectly for one of my devices, but did not on other devices. Looking at the drivers, I noticed that they were not recognized as "true" ftdi devices. If I could upvote twice... I would. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer
sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer"
cat /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide more details.